# How do I make Tikz make a curved arrow from one node to another when my nodes are in a straight line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (1) {a};
  \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {b};
  \node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {c};
  \node[main node] (4) [right of=3] {d};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [right] {} (2)
    (2) edge node [right] {} (3)
    (3) edge node [right] {} (4)
    (4) edge node [left] {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that produces this graph:

[image: bad graph]

My goal is to produce a graph like this:

[image: good graph]

Pardon the bad drawing. I tried various combinations of `(4) edge node [bend left] {} (1);` and `(4) edge node [loop left] {} (1);` to no avail.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Just to show another approach, this use case is exactly what the keys `bend left` and `bend right` were created for:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (1) {a};
  \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {b};
  \node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {c};
  \node[main node] (4) [right of=3] {d};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [right] {} (2)
    (2) edge node [right] {} (3)
    (3) edge node [right] {} (4)
    (4) edge[bend right] node [left] {} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

These keys also accept an optional `<angle>` value to simultaneously set the `in` and `out` keys symmetrically, so writing

```
(4) edge[bend right=90] node [left] {} (1);
```

will result in

[image]

If asymmetric setting of the `in` and `out` keys is required, [cfr's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228726/21344) is the way to go.

Answer (score 80):

One approach is to use `\draw` and specify the incoming and outgoing angles. Simply specifying the node names will construct the path with respect to the node center (although not draw from there). You can also specify node anchors. For example, the red line connects `(4.north)` to `(1.north)`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
\node[main node] (1) {a};
\node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {b};
\node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {c};
\node[main node] (4) [right of=3] {d};

\draw [->] (1) -- (2);
\draw [->] (2) -- (3);
\draw [->] (3) -- (4);
\draw [->] (4) to [out=150,in=30] (1);
\draw [->,red] (4.north) to [out=150,in=30] (1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) But it won't start from the centre of the node if you omit the explicit anchor. It will try to do something sensible instead. (See my example below which doesn't specify an explicit anchor but where the lines drawn still start from the edge. Indeed, your straight lines show the same phenomenon. Perhaps I didn't understand your point?)

Comment: I do see now what you are trying to say but it is a bit confusing, because the `path` is created with `\draw` but, clearly, it is *not drawn* from the `center`!

Comment: @cfr I meant the path is calculated with respect to the node center, but is not necessarily drawn all the way to the center. The arrow in the OP's figure was from the top of one node to the top of another, so I was just trying to illustrate how using different anchors can affect placement.

Answer (score 31):

There are several ways to draw curves, if that's the question. Here's one:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    ->,
    >=stealth',
    auto,node distance=3cm,
    thick,
    main node/.style={circle, draw, font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
    ]

  \node[main node] (1) {a};
  \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {b};
  \node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {c};
  \node[main node] (4) [right of=3] {d};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [right] {} (2)
    (2) edge node [right] {} (3)
    (3) edge node [right] {} (4);
  \draw
    (4) [out=150, in=20] to  (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: curve back]

Here's a way to make it part of the original `\path` using `edge` (and varying the angles a bit):

```
  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge node [right] {} (2)
    (2) edge node [right] {} (3)
    (3) edge node [right] {} (4)
    (4) edge [out=150, in=90]  (1);
```

[image: edge in path curves]

Comment: This is definitely the simplest solution; thank you for the help!

Comment: There's a simpler one: `(a) edge[bend left] (b)`

Comment: @yo' But that gives you less control e.g. if the intermediate notes are bigger and you need a steeper angle to go around them or whatever. So it is not really simpler because you need a second method for the cases where it isn't suitable.

Comment: ``edge[bend left]`` is immediate and intuitive, whereas it's not immediate what ``in`` and ``out`` control and what would be, say, the values of in and out that would recreate the effect of ``bend left``, let alone some other effect. (full disclosure: I haven't read the manual)