# Draw an axis with curved arrows in both directions in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

[image]

I was wondering how I could draw something like this in TIKZ? I have an axis with numbers, but I would like the letters and the arrows...

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{->-/.style={decoration={
  markings,
  mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{<}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% a straight line segment
\draw[latex-] (-2,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[->-=.6] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[-latex] (1,0) -- (2,0);
% the ticks and their labels
\foreach \x  in {-1,...,1}
  \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below,fill=white] {\the\numexpr\x +1\relax};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code. Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228730/124842

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
L/.style={very thick, draw=#1, looseness=2, ->}
                    ]
  \draw[very thick]    (0,0) -- + (7,0);
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,6}{\coordinate (x\x) at (\x,0);}
  \draw (x1)+(0,1mm) -- + (0,-2mm) node[below] {$s$}
        (x4)+(0,1mm) -- + (0,-2mm) node[below] {$t$};
  \draw[L=orange] (x1) to [out=90, in=90] (x2);
  \draw[L=orange] (x2) to [out=90, in=90] (x3);
  \draw[L=orange] (x3) to [out=90, in=90] (x6);
  \draw[L=blue]   (x6) to [out=90, in=90] (x5);
  \draw[L=blue]   (x5) to [out=90, in=90] (x4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```