# Draw commutative-type diagram with nodes TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I want to draw a diagram in TikZ which looks as follows:

[image]

I am not sure of what type of diagram it would classify as (not commutative?), my first thought was something similar to the example on page 7 of the tikz-cd manual:

[image]

but it doesn't feel like the most appropriate method.    Any pointers?

Comment: You can use `controls` as in my answer for your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617538/make-tikz-arrow-curvier/617543#617543

Comment: Take a look at the cover of Part II of the `pgfmanual` (page 102 in the current version). You're searching for the different loops, see section "74.4 Loops" of the manual.

Comment: You should alway post a MWE showing what you have tried https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, shorten <=0.2 cm, shorten >=0.3 cm]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,4);
\coordinate (C) at (4,0);
\fill (A) circle[radius=0.1 cm];
\fill (B) circle[radius=0.1 cm];
\fill (C) circle[radius=0.1 cm];
\draw (A) to[out=80,in=50,min distance=5cm] (A);
\draw (C) to[out=130,in=100,min distance=5cm] (C);
\draw (A) to[bend left] (C);
\draw (C) to[bend left] (A);
\draw (A) to[out=130,in=230,min distance=1.5cm] (A);
\draw (C) to[out=50,in=-50,min distance=1.5cm] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Diagram with three nodes and looped arrows]

**Edit:**

Just to show one of the curves with explicit control points:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{%
  show curve controls/.style={
    postaction={
      decoration={
        show path construction,
        curveto code={
          \draw [blue, >=\empty, shorten <=0 cm, shorten >=00 cm] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
            (\tikzinputsegmentlast) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb);
          \fill [red, opacity=0.5] 
            (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) circle [radius=.5ex]
            (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) circle [radius=.5ex];
            \coordinate (ConA) at (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta);
            \coordinate (ConB) at (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb);
        }
      },
      decorate
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->, shorten <=0.2 cm, shorten >=0.3 cm]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,4);
\coordinate (C) at (4,0);
\fill (A) circle[radius=0.1 cm];
\fill (B) circle[radius=0.1 cm];
\fill (C) circle[radius=0.1 cm];
\draw[thick, show curve controls] (A) to[out=80,in=50,min distance=5cm] (A); %Original curve
\draw[red] (A) .. controls +(ConA) and +(ConB) .. (A); %The same curve with control points
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: One curve with control points]

The same control point can also be calculated:

```
\draw (A) .. controls ({5*cos(80)},{5*sin(80)}) and ({5*cos(50)},{5*sin(50)}) .. (A);
```

---

A better way to draw the complete diagram would be to use `calc` to calculate the control points symmetrically in the desired direction. -I did not do this to keep the code simple and readable.

Comment: it is the right use of 'min distance' here

Comment: @hpekkristiansen In this figure, without `[min distance]` of the `to` operation, it seems hard to control distance from node to a desired distance.

Comment: @hpekkristiansen Never mind! perhaps I have not realized `[min distance]` until seeing your code. I often use `.. controls +(P) and +(Q) ..` by my habit

Comment: @BlackMild: This is just an alternative way of setting the control points with angles and distance instead of coordinates.

Comment: do you mind drawing the same figure using `.. controls +(P) and +(Q) ..` ?

Comment: @BlackMild: I did one of the curves.

Answer (score 1):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
    column sep=6pt, 
    every matrix/.append style={name=mycd},  
    execute at end picture={
        \draw [->] plot [smooth, tension=3] coordinates { (mycd-2-1.80) (mycd-1-2.-135) (mycd-2-1.50)};
        \draw [->] plot [smooth, tension=3] coordinates { (mycd-2-3.130) (mycd-1-2.-45) (mycd-2-3.100)};
        }
    ] 
& A & \\[10pt]
B \ar[rr, bend right]\ar[loop left, <-] & & C \ar[ll, bend right]\ar[loop right]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And in case your node are all black points:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=6pt, 
    every matrix/.append style={
        name=mycd, 
        nodes={circle, fill=black, outer sep= 2pt, inner sep=3pt}
        },  
    execute at end picture={
        \draw [->] plot [smooth, tension=3] coordinates { (mycd-2-1.80) (mycd-1-2.-135) (mycd-2-1.50)};
        \draw [->] plot [smooth, tension=3] coordinates { (mycd-2-3.130) (mycd-1-2.-45) (mycd-2-3.100)};
       }
    ] 
& {} & \\[10pt]
{} \ar[rr, bend right]\ar[loop left, <-] & & {} \ar[ll, bend right]\ar[loop right]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]