# Distance of edges from each other

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
    \node[state,initial, initial text=O] (q0) {$q_0$};
    \node[state,right=3cm of q0] (q1) {$q_1$};
    \node[state,right=3cm of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
    \node[state,right=3cm of q2] (q3) {$q_3$};
    \draw (q0) edge[bend left] node{true} (q3);
    \draw (q0) edge[bend left=2cm] node{false} (q3);
    \draw (q0) edge[bend left=4cm] node{predicate} (q3);
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
```

This is the result:
[image: The result I don't want]

I thought that adding values to `bend left` may make these edges more apart from each other. But it doesn't. How can I resolve that ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617540/197451

Comment: Use `[bend left,looseness=<number>]` and adjust the looseness value.

Answer (score 2):

I just copied and pasted your code snippet so no tikzset are taken in account. Next time, please include a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in your question.

In the following you can see two different options, one with `bend` and `looseness`, and one with `out=<>,in=<>` and `looseness`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
    \node[state,initial, initial text=O] (q0) {$q_0$};
    \node[state,right=3cm of q0] (q1) {$q_1$};
    \node[state,right=3cm of q1] (q2) {$q_2$};
    \node[state,right=3cm of q2] (q3) {$q_3$};
    \draw (q0) edge[bend left] node[above]{true} (q3);
    \draw (q0) edge[bend left=2cm,looseness=1] node[above]{false} (q3);
    \draw (q0) edge[out=90,in=90,looseness=1.5] node[above]{predicate} (q3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: bend]